# Partial declarations, must not specify different base classes?

Tags: wpf, xaml

When I changed this:

```
public partial class FrmCategories : UserControl
```

to this:

```
public partial class FrmCategories : MyUserControl
```

Where `MyUserControl` inherits from `UserControl`.

I got this error:

> Error 2   Partial declarations of 'WpfTest.FrmCategories' must not
>   specify different base classes
>
> \Projects\WpfTest\WpfTest\FrmCategories.xaml.cs   21  26  WpfTest

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfTest.FrmCategories"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"

             xmlns:we="clr-namespace:WpfTest"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" Background="Azure" Height="131" Width="229">
    <StackPanel Margin="5,24,5,0" Name="catFrm" Height="75" VerticalAlignment="Top">
```

I'm beginning WPF (as the name of the project implies), so I expect a trivial error here

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to change the root element of the XAML file:

```
<we:MyUserControl x:Class="WpfTest.FrmCategories"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:we="clr-namespace:WpfTest"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" Background="Azure" Height="131" Width="229">
    <StackPanel Margin="5,24,5,0" Name="catFrm" Height="75" VerticalAlignment="Top">
</we:MyUserControl>
```

Comment: Does `we` have a special meaning, or I can name it to any thing?

Comment: It is a namespace mapping that you have defined: xmlns:we="clr-namespace:WpfTest"

Comment: "Error 3 The name "MyUserControl" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:WpfTest". E:\Maged Zakzouk\Projects\WpfTest\WpfTest\Frm"

Comment: What is the namespace of your UC?

Comment: it is just the root: `WpfTest`

Comment: And it is defined in the application project and called "MyUserControl"? Did you try to build and run the app?

Comment: Yes, I did build the project, the file name is also MyUserControl.cs

Comment: As this is Error 3, maybe your build failed earlier because of Error1 and Error 2 (whatever they are)? As a consequence, there would not be a class MyUserControl and thus Error3 would be thrown...

Answer (score 3):

`partial` only means that you can split the class definition into different files. But still all the partial definitions define only one class which as such may only have one base class.

If you want to inherit from `MyUserControl`, you have to change the xaml code, too:

```
<we:MyUserControl x:Class="WpfTest.FrmCategories"
...>
...
</we:MyUserControl>
```

Also, notice that you only have to specify the base class once, i.e. you could even change the C# code to

```
public partial class FrmCategories
```

because the base class has been defined in the xaml.